# ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle is displayed using py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe, cx-oracle

I'm trying to create my python testcode using tkinter and cx_Oracle modules into an executable format using py2exe, but an error is displayed as shown below.

```
raise ImportError "No module names" + qname
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

If i run the script as it is, it works fine but not as executable.
The setup.py file contains the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
#setup(console=['db_connect.py'])
setup(
    windows=['db_connect.py'],
    options={
        "py2exe":{
                "packages": ["cx_Oracle"],
                 }
            }
    )
```

What needs to be done to solve this?

Comment: have you tried `pyinstaller`, it catches most dependencies by itselve

Comment: I tried with pyinstaller, I'm getting ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Failed to execute script db_connect. I copied oraociei12.dll to the current folder and checked, but the error does appear when i start the executable file. Oracleclient is aded in environmental variable, where else i need to check?